# Why does gcc error on sizeof typedef'ed pointer

Tags: c

Working with this code

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                  
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                 
struct nodetag {                                                                                    
        struct nodetag *next;                                                                       
        struct nodetag *prev;                                                                       
        int a;                                                                                      
};                                                                                                  
typedef struct nodetag *node;                                                                       

int main(void)                                                                                      
{                                                                                                   
        node h;                                                                                     
        printf("%zu\n",sizeof(struct nodetag));                                                      
        printf("%zu\n",sizeof(*h));                                                                  
        printf("%zu\n",sizeof(*node));                                                               
}
```

Compiling this code results in:

```
expected expression before ‘node’  
printf("%u\n",sizeof(*node));
```

Why does the compiler error on sizeof(*node) but not on sizeof(*h) ?

Comment: `node` is a type, not a pointer. You can't dereference it.

Comment: The same reason you can't use `sizeof(*(int*))`

Comment: See also: [is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: The argument to `sizeof` can either be a type or an expression. You can't mix them, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typedef` creates an *alias* name for other data type. That means, the statement

```
typedef struct nodetag *node;
```

creates `node` as an alias of `struct nodetag *` type.
This statement

```
sizeof(*node)
```

is same as

```
sizeof(*(struct node *))
```

You cannot dereference a *type*, hence you are getting error on this statement. You can dereference a pointer variable as you are doing in this statement

```
printf("%u\n",sizeof(*h));
```

This is valid as the `h` is of type `node` which is an alias of `struct nodetag *` type. Dereferencing `h` will give `struct nodetag`.

Also, the type of the result of `sizeof` operator is `size_t`. You should use `%zu` format specifier instead of `%u`.